# Link to remote PDF file fails under Android

Tags: java, android, itext

I'm using iText 5 to generate a PDF file with a link to a remote file and using the following code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File("pdf/TestLink.pdf")));
document.open();
document.add(new Chunk("link").setAnchor("Tunesbook.pdf"));
document.close();
```

The resulting PDF works fine on my Linux desktop, click on "link" opens the file "Tunesbook.pdf", but when I use it on Android nothing happens. How can I make it work on Android?

I also tried versions using `chunk.setRemoteGoto` or `PdfAction.gotoRemotePage` which all worked on my desktop but failed on Android.

I used Acrobat reader to read the PDF on both, Android and Linux desktop.

Comment: Which app is displaying your pdf file? And how was this app started?

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(new File("pdf/TestLink.pdf"))` Sorry, but i cannot believe that such a relative path could work. Please tell full path of where this file is created.

Comment: Why do you call it a 'remote' file? It's not on the internet we know.

Comment: I used Acrobat reader to read the PDF on both, Android and Linux desktop, see my edited question. The relative path works fine on Linux desktop. remote file in the sense of a non internal link

Comment: How does Acrobat reader know about your file? Tell scenario. How was it started with your file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show PDF Files, you can use the structure below.

```
File file = new File("path-to-pdf-file");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Alternatively, you can use [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: Where exactly does your answer refer to the OP's problem with *Link to remote PDF file* from within another PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to:

- Add iText dependency to your app level gradle file, e.g. implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13'
- Add READ/WRITE permission to your manifest file for example:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
- Create a Document instance, e.g. Document document = new Document()
- Get a PdfWriter instance and supply it with the document and the output file path, e.g. PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file))
- Open the document and add content, e.g. document.open(); document.add(new Paragraph("Hello PDF"))
- Close the document, e.g. document.close()

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Where exactly does your answer refer to the OP's problem with *Link to remote PDF file* from within another PDF file?

Comment: I have no problem to open the file on Andorid, I see the link but the link does not work, meaning the file "Tunesbook.pdf" does not open. I use the same file structure on Linux and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter the same problem as when the user uses the Files app and tries to display an .html file with Chrome or other browser and the html source contains img tags with relative src paths.

The browser wil receive a content scheme uri and permission to read the html file.

To read the image it would change the content scheme for the last path segment often representing the file name.

But for this new uri it has no permission to read the file hence a blank.

The same for Acrobat reader.

Even if it manages to build a nice uri for the other pdf file it has no read permission for it.

Comment: The relative path is used on creation time only. The file TestLink.pdf is createdin the same directory as Tunesbook.pdf through a Java program using iText. When i open TestLink.pdf with Acrobat reader the problem occurs on Android only, but there is no relative path involved. PDF code is <</Subtype/Link/Rect[36 785.52 54 796.62]/A<</S/URI/URI(Tunesbook.pdf)>>/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 1]>>

Comment: That clearly is a relative path. Even only a file name. Yes it will be in the same directory but Acrobat reader can not load it as it has not a single idea about wich directory. Or if it has it has no read access for the constructed uri. Further you should read my answer again as it is like it is. I gave you the reason. No solution as there is not. You cannot make it work with an external application. You could add a pdf viewer component to the app that created both files. Then you are done.